# Accessing a specific node in local service fabric cluster

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-stateful

I am working on a Service Fabric Application, in which I am running my Application that contains a bunch of ASP.NET Core Web APIs. Now when I run my application on my local service fabric cluster that is configured with 5 nodes, the application runs successfully and I am able to send post requests the exposed Web APIs. Actually I want to hit the code running on a same cluster node with different post requests to the different exposed APIs on that particular node.

For further explanation, for example there is an API exposed on Node '0' that accept a post request and execute a Job from the exe service running on the Node '0', and also there is an API that abort the running job. Now when I request to execute a Job, it starts to execute on Node '0' but when I try to abort the Job, the service fabric cluster forward the request to a different node for example say node '1'. In resulting I could not able to abort the running Job because there is no running Job available on Node '1'. I don't know how to handle this situation.

For this situation, there are solutions like maintaining a storage that will hold some unique ID before starting to process the Job and return the ID to the caller. Now when one wants to abort the Job, he/she call the api sending the id to be aborted but here again the problem is inside my running services there are multiple threads running. I want to abort those running thread. These threads are found only on that particular node on which the job is running. so somehow I have to reach to that particular node.

For states, I am using a Statefull service of type ASP.Net Core Web API and running the app on 5 nodes of my local service fabric cluster.

Please suggest what should be the best approach.

Answer (score 1):

As Patrick pointed, I have answered a similar question here: 
[sending-request-to-asp-net-core-web-api-running-on-a-specific-node-in-a-service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48620058/sending-request-to-asp-net-core-web-api-running-on-a-specific-node-in-a-service)

You are having problems because the way you have designed your system.
You should not rely on the node running the task, but in the task itself, because it might get deactivated or moved, and also is hard to scale if you keep both in the same node.

There are many approaches to solve this problem, in the question I referenced there are a few where you can start.